# How to remove header authentication while logout?

Tags: angularjs

Hi i am using header authentication for web service call it os working fine.

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(Username + ':' + password);
      $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
          success(function(data) {
              if(data=='' || data==null || data=='undefined'){
                  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                      title: 'Info!',
                      template: 'Invalid Password, or no user found with this Email Address'
                  });
                  alertPopup.then(function(res) {
                      console.log('Invalid Password, or no user found with this Email Address ');
                  });
```

problem is if i logged out and then try to login with different username or password it getting logged in with first logged in user .how to remove the header authentication while logout?

Comment: why you dont use tokens? when login, server sends you token and each http request uses this token. Since logout was pressed, you just remove token.

Comment: server is not sending any token. web service is written like this

Comment: is there any other way to remove the header authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = ''
```

to your logout call?

Cheers

Comment: Thanks yes but even after trying this it getting logged in with wrong header .i think need to delete permanently is there any way for that?

Comment: The above code should clear the Authorization header, unless something is caching the header in-between. You can also try $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic '. If you can, please use a tool like fiddler and see whats really being send to the server on the headers and whether the results are cached.

Comment: Thanks a lot i got the  problem it os caching in backend, so need web service for this one

Comment: Hi i tried the above code and also tried deleting the cookies also, but it is not working can you please help me

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late already but try with:

```
delete $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
```

It works for me.